# Conditional and normal select

Tags: jquery, select

I have a well-functioning conditional select with two select boxes.
However, I would like to be able to use the first select as a normal select, and display items with a certain class name, and then, if the user wants to narrow it down, he can use the sub select in order to display only one item.

[See jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/aCahZ/).

If you select "Apple", then you need to select one of the Apple models in the sub select. I would like to be able to display all Apple models (for instance with class="apple"), if you select "Apple" in the first select box.

I have tried to write some code to start with - but it's not working.:

```
 var selectedprod = $("#selectprod").val();
 $(".ct-content-container-box").hide();
 $('.' + selectedprod).parent('.ct-content-container-box').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
 $('#selector').blur();
```

Can anyone give me a hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out. Different approach without switch statements. [my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qwy3g/)

```
$selectprod = $('#selectprod');
$selector = $('#selector');

$selectprod.change(function() {
    $options = $('.ct-content-container-box.skin-white');
    $selector.empty();
    $selector.append("<option value='showall'>Sub select</option>");

    $options.show();
    $currentSelection = $(this).val();
    if ($currentSelection != "showallprod") {
        $options.children().each(function() {
            if (!($(this).hasClass($currentSelection))) {
                $(this).parent($options).hide();
            } else {
                $selector.append("<option value='" + $(this).attr('id') + "'>" + $(this).text() + "</option>");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Also, no reason to add the sub select options manually, as the values already exist in the HTML.

Comment: This is a perfect solution. Smaller code, easier maintenance. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only problem here is case sensitivity. Your values start with capital letters, but corresponding classes do not. Just added `.toLowerCase()` and it seems to be working:

```
$('#selectprod').change(function() {

    var selectedprod = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".ct-content-container-box").hide();
    $('.' + selectedprod).parent('.ct-content-container-box').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
    $('#selector').blur();

});​
```

See updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aCahZ/2/).